# How to delete all text except for what's between two strings (Notepad++)

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have to truncate all loginIDs from a 17k file.  How do I delete all text except for what's between two strings?

EG:

```
<USER_LOGIN_ID>user1</USER_LOGIN_ID>

<USER_LOGIN_ID>user2</USER_LOGIN_ID>

<USER_LOGIN_ID>user3</USER_LOGIN_ID>

<USER_LOGIN_ID>user4</USER_LOGIN_ID>
```

would leave

user1

user2

user3

user4

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly complex regular expression:

Find: `<USER_LOGIN_ID>([^<]*)</USER_LOGIN_ID>`
Replace: `$1`

Here you are matching `<USER_LOGIN_ID>`, followed by any number of characters which are not `<`, followed by `</USER_LOGIN_ID>`. The brackets `()` mark the central text as a field, and `$1` in the replacement string expands to this matched field only.

For the instance you show of only one match per line, you can use the slightly simpler find string `<USER_LOGIN_ID>(.*)</USER_LOGIN_ID>`, but this will fail if there are two log-ins per line.

If there are several log-ins on a single line, the first find will concatenate the strings unless there is intervening punctuation in the source text (if not you'll have to add it to the replacement string, eg `$1` - with following space).

You will of course need to mark regular expression (and probably match case) in the options.

Answer (score 0):

Search for:

```
<USER_LOGIN_ID>(.*?)</USER_LOGIN_ID>
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

The expression `.*?` represents the shortest possible text that falls between the two specified tags. (The question mark makes the matching non-greedy.)