# Notepad++: Find a Method in a source code and delete it except of the argument

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have several thousend files of code. For the future I need to get rid of a method but I want do keep the argument in the same line. I would like to solve the problem with regex in Nodepad++

The Method looks like this

```
self.result(lib.file.SetValue('set accelerator', False, subtitle='Disable mode(auto)'))
```

As a result I want the following content

```
lib.file.SetValue('set accelerator', False, subtitle='Disable mode(auto)')
```

So I need to get rid of `self.result(` and of the last parentheses `)`

I found in another thread a similar problem

[How to delete all text except for what's between two strings (Notepad++)](https://superuser.com/questions/1259945/how-to-delete-all-text-except-for-whats-between-two-strings-notepad)

It is obvious that I can't do the following

search for:

```
self.result(([^))]*)        #Match "self.result("  followed by any
                            #number of characters which are not "))"

replace with \1)            #replace with what is in between and 
                            #add a parentheses
```

Can someone help me out?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

#### I need to get rid of a method but I want do keep the arguments in the same line

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `self.result\((.*)\)\R`.
- Set "Replace with" to `\1`
- Enable "Regular expression" and "matches newline"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

Notes:

- Use `\r\n` for Windows EOLs
- Use `\n` for Unix/OSX EOLs
- Use `\r` for Mac OS (up to version 9) EOLs
- Alternatively use `\R` which should work on every OS

Before:

```
self.result(lib.file.SetValue('set accelerator', False, subtitle='Disable mode(auto)'))
```

After:

```
lib.file.SetValue('set accelerator', False, subtitle='Disable mode(auto)')
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)